# Swift IOS Overlay

Tags: swift, mapkit

My IOS map isn't rendering the NOAA tiles on top of it. Can someone give my a clue what is wrong? Here is my viewcontroler. It's just a standard mapkit viewer. Anyways, it is not working and is just giving me a standard satellite map when I run this code. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks for any help you can give me.

Have a great rest of your weekend.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    //Linking MapView
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.mapView.delegate = self

        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite

        let centre = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.2189, longitude: -76.0690)

       let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)

       let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centre, span: span)
       self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
       self.mapView.regionThatFits(region)



       let template = "https://tileservice.charts.noaa.gov/tiles/50000_1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"

       let carte_indice = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate:template)


       carte_indice.isGeometryFlipped = true

       carte_indice.canReplaceMapContent = false


       self.mapView.addOverlay(carte_indice)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func mapView(
        mapView: MKMapView!, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer!
    {

    if overlay is MKTileOverlay{
        var renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay:overlay)
        renderer.alpha = 0.8
        return renderer
    }
        return nil
    }


}
```

Comment: You got a typo in the template url string, try without the ' after .png

Comment: Yeah, I figure that out earlier. Thanks!

Comment: So now it's working properly?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: First of all, please update your question when you find errors. Further, this code is not for iOS 14. I pasted the code into Xcode, and had to do some tweaks to make it run. Setting a break point where you return the renderer, made it possible to inspect the tiles. Apparently you are not getting tiles from the server, therefor the map is shown as you defined in self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of mulling over it, I solved my issue. Posting the solution if anyone needs it.

Thanks to GJ Nilsen for helping me figure this out. The problem was that the NOAA tiles didn't have coverage for everywhere, so I solved it by simplify forcing it to load.

```
if overlay is MKTileOverlay{
    var renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay:overlay)
    renderer.alpha = 0.8
    return renderer
}
else{
    var renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay:overlay)
    renderer.alpha = 0.8
    return renderer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The NOAA RNC Map Tile server is being taken out of commission, and some of the tiles my app uses started being disrupted around the same time you posted this question.  This is part of the larger transfer from Raster to Electronic charting, and NOAA's discontinuation of paper charts.

https://nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/updates/coast-survey-to-shut-down-the-raster-navigational-chart-tile-service-and-other-related-services/

I am working to find a similar solution, but all of the new services I have found require a pay model of some sort (MBTile conversion, ArcGIS, etc) ... I miss the good old free NOAA map tiles!